# Doorbell has 16 volts at the door, but when I connect the doorbell it drops to 2v

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I already changed the transformer, 16v at the transformer 16 at the door, but when I plug in my nest wired doorbell, no power meter reads 2v. I already ordered a replacement doorbell but could anything else cause this?

Comment: First question does the doorbell work? Second question did you ground one side of your 16v circuit? If you didn't you may just be dealing with a floating voltage with no reference.

Comment: How many VA is the transformer, and how many VA does the fancy doorbell need? Very easy to have a transformer that puts out voltage at no current be wiped out when a load wants more current than it can deliver.

Comment: 16v 30 amp should be fine.

Comment: Well over 400VA I would consider that a bit oversized. I think you meant 30VA

Comment: Yes 30 va, sorry about that.

Comment: What's the voltage at the chime?  If the voltage at the transformer is 16V, then voltage across the Nest + voltage across the chime must be 16V (minus a fraction of a volt for voltage drop).

Comment: I'm getting 16v at the door until the nest is connected, then it drops to 2.5v no power, there is no chime.